# How to paginate a sorted Jekyll collection?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I am trying to create left/right arrow links that navigate to the previous/next pages in a collection. This is simple to implement for the standard collection:

```
{% if page.previous %}
  <a href="{{ page.previous.url }}>Left arrow</a>
{% endif %}
{% if page.next %}
  <a href="{{ page.next.url }}>Right arrow</a>
{% endif %}
```

The problem I have is that this just cycles through the collection in file order. I need to specify a specific order for the pages using a frontmatter variable (`position`).

I have searched far and wide but all the information to do with sorting seems to apply to site navigation rather than pagination. It appears that I need to use a liquid for loop after assigning the sorted collection to a variable. I'm struggling to get the `page.previous` and `page.next` variables working within this loop.

I've attempted to loop through the documents in the sorted collection and only output the navigation arrows when the document URL matches the current page, but that doesn't seem to work:

```
{% assign sorted_collection site.collection | sort: "position" %}

{% for document in sorted_collection %}

  {% if document.url == page.url %}

    {% if document.previous %}
      <a href="{{ document.previous.url }}>Left arrow</a>
    {% endif %}

    {% if document.next %}
      <a href="{{ document.next.url }}>Right arrow</a>
    {% endif %}

  {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

Am I missing something in my liquid syntax or am I going down completely the wrong route with my logic here?

My current hacky solution is to preface the document filenames with numbers to ensure they are in the correct order by default. This won't work when I hand the site over however, as there's no way I can trust non-technical content creators with keeping the filenames in order.

Answer (score 2):

The technique you linked is pretty much what I use for next/previous in collection. In case the link ever goes stale, here's a similar snippet that saves the collection item object rather than just the URL:

```
{% if page.collection %}
  {% assign collection = site[page.collection] | sort: 'position' %}
  {% assign prev = collection | last %}
  {% assign next = collection | first %}

  {% for item in collection %}
    {% if item.title == page.title %}
      {% unless forloop.first %}
        {% assign prev = iterator %}
      {% endunless %}

      {% unless forloop.last %}
        {% assign next = collection[forloop.index] %}
      {% endunless %}
    {% endif %}

    {% assign iterator = item %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}

{% if prev %}
  <a href="{{ prev.url }}">{{ prev.title }}</a>
{% endif %}

{% if next %}
  <a href="{{ next.url }}">{{ next.title }}</a>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found and tested the solution [suggested here](http://halfapx.com/en/previous-and-next-links-within-jekyll-collections/) and it works! I think the trick is in capturing the collection name and assigning it to a variable as a string.

Does anyone have a better/less verbose way of doing this?